# Selecting from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need your help. Suppose I've the following fake table 
[image]

and another fake table 
[image]

What I want to is to come up with the following table

[image]

```
select b.Country, b.AnotherCode, a.Code from Country1 a, Country2 b where a.Country=b.Country
```

(Primary key is country) But it doesn't show last two rows. How to do so that it will retrieve all rows as showed in the last table. Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select b.Country, b.AnotherCode, a.Code from Country1 a left join Country2 b on a.Country=b.Country
```

Use a left join

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the intersection of the two sets - if you want all rows from either set, you can use a full join:

```
SELECT      COALESCE(a.Country, b.Country) AS Country, 
            COALESCE(b.AnotherCode, 0) AS AnotherCode, 
            COALESCE(a.Code, 0) AS Code
FROM        Country1 a
FULL JOIN   Country2 b 
    ON      a.Country = b.Country
```

Of course, if you only wanted records from `Country1` and any correspondingvalues from `Country2`, then a `LEFT JOIN` would suffice. Similarly, if you wanted a different default value when the join fails, change the value in the `COALESCE`